# Sort A Multi Dimensional Array In Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, controller

[image]

This is the result of dd() that I use in my controller on laravel 8. I want to sort the data based on the JB column. I can't use the manual order by in SQL syntax because I get JB from complex DB RAW. Therefore I want to sort this multi-dimensional array using php. Does anyone know how to sort the multi-dimensional array based on JB column value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here I go...
you can use `array_multisort` PHP function. [Link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php)

```
$new = [
    [
        'id' => 13,
        'name' => 'Tony',
        'jb' => 3,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 15,
        'name' => 'Joe',
        'jb' => 2,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 16,
        'name' => 'Ross',
        'jb' => 1,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 18,
        'name' => 'Monika',
        'jb' => 5,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 20,
        'name' => 'Joye',
        'jb' => 7,
    ],
];
$keys = array_column($new, 'jb');
array_multisort($keys, SORT_ASC, $new);
```

so as a result you will get link,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 16
            [name] => Ross
            [jb] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [name] => Joe
            [jb] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [name] => Tony
            [jb] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 18
            [name] => Monika
            [jb] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 20
            [name] => Joye
            [jb] => 7
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

[sortBy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sortby) method solves your issue. Laravel really has a strong bunch of methods in collections. Below code block shows an example.

```php
$collection = collect([
    ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
    ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
]);

$sorted = $collection->sortBy('price');

$sorted->values()->all();

/*
    [
        ['name' => 'Chair', 'price' => 100],
        ['name' => 'Bookcase', 'price' => 150],
        ['name' => 'Desk', 'price' => 200],
    ]
*/
```